# How to get the matrix elements of an SVG transform attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, matrix

I got a svg code containing a `<text>` like that

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 581 207)" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="120">TEXT</text>
```

In order a plugin to work I need to create "x" and "y" attributes referring to the two last values of the `matrix()` . i.e 581 and 207

How to get the values in order to do something like `jQuery(this).attr("x", *theValue*)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr()` to get the full `matrix(...)` string. However to pull out the final two values you'll need to manipulate the string a little. To do that you could use a regular expression, like this:

```js
var t = $('text').attr('transform').match(/(\d+)/g);
var m4 = t[4];
var m5 = t[5];
console.log(m4, m5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 581 207)" font-family="Arial" font-size="120">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks again. It has been implemented and works like a charm.. I feel a bit silly but I'm beginning with javascript and I could'nt find answers on the web with the way I was formulating the problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 4):

The [SVG DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix) provides access to the matrix. No parsing, splitting or string conversion is required.

```js
let m = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].transform.animVal[0].matrix;

console.log(`matrix: ${m.a} ${m.b} ${m.c} ${m.d} ${m.e}  ${m.f}`)
```

```html
<svg>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 581 207)" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="120">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```